# Very slow post request with Swift's URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: swift

I'm currently porting an Android app over to iOS and I've noticed a significant decrease in performance for my HTTPS post requests. On Android, using Java `HttpsURLConnection` objects, post requests would take about 0.5-1.0 seconds on average (for transferring a maximum of about 100 characters). On Swift, using `URLSession.shared.dataTask` to perform the same post requests takes anywhere from half a second to 15 seconds, sometimes timing out.

One trend I've noticed is that, while running the app, the various requests that are made are either all slow (> 5 seconds) or all faster. The time for requests sporadically changes every time the app is restarted.

Below is my current dataTask code. `getResponse` and `onSuccess` are functions for response handling, but I've found that they aren't what's slowing down the requests. From a few "tests" (print statements), it seems like the slow-downs occur as network connections are first being established.

```
func execute() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://website.com") else {
        print("ERROR > INVALID URL")
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postDataString = "data"

    guard let requestBody: Data = postDataString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        print("ERROR > FAILED TO ENCODE POST STRING")
        return
    }
    request.httpBody = requestBody

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let unwrappedError = error {
            print("ERROR > FAILED TO CONNECT TO SERVER: \(error)")
            return
        }

        guard let unwrappedData = data else {
            print("ERROR > FAILED TO GET DATA")
            return
        }

        guard let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B") else {
            print("ERROR > FAILED TO DECODE RESPONSE TO STRING")
            return
        }

        let dataStringLines: [String] = dataString.components(separatedBy: "\n")

        guard let unwrappedGetResponse = self.getResponse else {
            print("ERROR > getResponse FUNCTION UNINITIALIZED")
            return
        }
        let success: Bool = unwrappedGetResponse(dataStringLines)

        if (success) {
            guard let unwrappedOnSuccess = self.onSuccess else {
                print("ERROR > onSuccess FUNCTION UNINITIALIZED")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                unwrappedOnSuccess()
            }
        }
        else {
            print("ERROR > BAD SERVER RESPONSE")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Some additional information:** I'm testing the code with an iPhone 5S running iOS 12.4.5. The app is targeting iOS 10.0.

Any idea on what could cause such inconsistent performance?

Comment: I've never experienced a slowdown such as you are describing — certainly not 15 seconds or timing out. You are not showing enough code, and a data task is not a post request, so it's quite difficult to understand what you are doing. Can you show the rest of the code. Until you do, here are some other idea: How are you testing? Are you running a real app or is this just a playground? And is there a good reason why you are using the `shared` URLSession? After all, it is shared; why not use your own personal session?

Comment: @matt I've edited the question to address most of your comments. As for your comment on using a personal URLSession, I'd need clarification on what you mean by that (I'm fairly new to Swift).